# LEFT JOIN with missing dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have a data table (`FACT.UnitData`) with  columns (`DayCalendarDate` and `SalesQty`) but some missing data:

```
DayCalendarDate             SalesQty
2019-05-13 00:00:00.0000000 36
2019-05-11 00:00:00.0000000 105
2019-05-10 00:00:00.0000000 50
2019-05-09 00:00:00.0000000 30
2019-05-08 00:00:00.0000000 22
```

I have another table (`DIM.DayCalendar`) with 1 column (`Date`) that is continuous and thus has no missing dates:

```
Date
2019-05-13 00:00:00.0000000
2019-05-12 00:00:00.0000000
2019-05-11 00:00:00.0000000
2019-05-10 00:00:00.0000000
2019-05-09 00:00:00.0000000
2019-05-08 00:00:00.0000000
```

**I want to join these two tables and fill the missing date  (2019-05-12) in `FACT.UnitData` with 0.0, please.** So far I have the following:

```
DECLARE @unit_id INT = 71907
DECLARE @location_id INT = 59

   SELECT dc.Date, ud.SalesQty
     FROM DIM.DayCalendar AS dc
LEFT JOIN FACT.UnitData AS ud
       ON dc.Date = ud.DayCalendarDate
    WHERE ud.UnitID = @unit_id AND ud.LocationID = @location_id
 ORDER BY dc.Date DESC
```

but this does not fill in the missing date (2019-05-12) with 0.0.

Thanks for any help here.

Comment: Are you sure? What if you order by `c.Date`?

Comment: Based on the `(NOLOCK)` query hint, this looks like `SQL-Server`, not `MySQL`. Have you tagged correctly? Also, you may wish to read this - [Bad habits : Putting NOLOCK everywhere](https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/)

Comment: `WITH (NOLOCK)` is a SQL Server hint, so I changed that tag.  Having said that, you should not be using it, unless you really know what you are doing.

Comment: @alex_lewis . . . What do you want the value filled with?

Comment: Learn what LEFT JOIN returns: INNER JOIN rows plus unmatched left table rows extended by NULLs. Always know what INNER JOIN you want as part of a LEFT JOIN. A WHERE or ON that requires a right table column to be not NULL after a LEFT JOIN ON removes any rows extended by NULLs, ie leaves only INNER JOIN rows, ie "turns LEFT JOIN into INNER JOIN". You have that.

Comment: This is a faq. Please always google many clear, concise & specific versions/phrasings of your question/problem/goal with & without your particular strings/names & read many answers. Add relevant keywords you discover to your searches. If you don't find an answer then post, using 1 variant search as title & keywords for tags. See the downvote arrow mouseover text. When you do have a non-duplicate code question to post please read & act on Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DECLARE @unit_id INT = 71907
DECLARE @location_id INT = 59

SELECT dc.Date, ud.SalesQty
 FROM DIM.DayCalendar AS dc
  LEFT JOIN FACT.UnitData AS ud
   ON dc.Date = ud.DayCalendarDate
 WHERE ud.UnitID = @unit_id AND ud.LocationID = @location_id
 ORDER BY dc.Date DESC
```

The query as of the point in time I am seeing it (I see no NOLOCKs, and perhaps other edits have been made) would be executed in SQL like so:

First, data from `DIM.DayCalendar AS dc` would be processed.

There is no filtering being done on this table, so all rows will be retrieved at this step.

Next, the join to `FACT.UnitData AS ud` is processed. As an LOJ, all rows from the first table remain (still no filtering), and and rows found in the second will be joined in. This may result in rows from the first table appearing more than once (i.e. once for every joined row in the second table). More importantly, where no rows are found in the second table, their values will be set to NULL.

Next the WHERE clause is considered: `ud.UnitID = @unit_id AND ud.LocationID = @location_id`. “ud” is the second table, so all rows that do not meet these qualifications will be filtered out. This means that when NULLs are found, the where clause resolves to False, and so all rows where no data was retrieved from the second table will be filtered out.

This is how you are losing your dates – the outer join is successful, but then all “no data found” rows are being removed. The next effect is the same as if you’d made it an inner join.

The most direct fix is to move the filterig criteria into the join clause, like so:

```
SELECT dc.Date, ud.SalesQty
 FROM DIM.DayCalendar AS dc
  LEFT JOIN FACT.UnitData AS ud
   ON dc.Date = ud.DayCalendarDate
    AND ud.UnitID = @unit_id
    AND ud.LocationID = @location_id
 ORDER BY dc.Date DESC
```

This will find fewer joined rows in the second table, but—since it is an outer join—all rows from the first table will be included in the result set.

Another version would be to check for NULLs in the where clause:

```
SELECT dc.Date, ud.SalesQty
 FROM DIM.DayCalendar AS dc
  LEFT JOIN FACT.UnitData AS ud
   ON dc.Date = ud.DayCalendarDate
 WHERE ud.UnitID = isnull(@unit_id, ud.UnitID)
  AND ud.LocationID = isnull(@location_id, ud.LocationID)
ORDER BY dc.Date DESC
```

Note that this would probably perform a bit more poorly than the first query. Both queries are a bit harder to read and understand, but that’s going to happen for complex queries.

Comment: Thanks a lot -- works perfectly in conjunction with the answer from @GordonLinoff (using the COALESCE method).

Answer (score 4):

Do you just need `coalesce()`?

```
SELECT c.Date, COALESCE(ud.SalesQty, 0) as SalesQty
FROM DIM.DayCalendar c LEFT JOIN
     FACT.UnitData AS ud
     ON c.Date = ud.DayCalendarDate
ORDER BY c.Date DESC;
```

Also note that the `ORDER BY` uses the calendar date, not the reference value.  After all, that would be `NULL` so it would not be in the right order.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. This appears not to work however. I only have read privileges on the server, could this be why?

Comment: You should only need read privileges and there is definitely nothing wrong with the query. See example here (no change other than schema name) https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=b75eae463358213beb1f5fb2f14f9226

Comment: @alex_lewis "This appears not to work" what do you mean by this?

Comment: @HoneyBadger By not work, I mean it does not fill the missing date (2012-05-12), all other dates are returned though.

Comment: @GarethD Thanks for clearing that up. Perhaps it's because I have a `WHERE ud.UnitID = @unit_id AND ud.LocationID = @location_id` clause before the `ORDER BY` statement? Thanks again.

Comment: @alex_lewis . . . The `left join` will return *all* rows in the calendar table, with a value for the sales.  This is what your question asks for.  You can move your `WHERE` conditions to the `ON` clause, if you need to add them.  I note that your question makes no mention of such conditions.

Comment: I can never decide whether to use COALESCE or ISNULL for these kind of things?

Comment: @MartinBrown . . . In SQL Server, `ISNULL()` has better performance *when the first expression is complicated (`coalesce()` evaluates it twice).  However, `coalesce()` is both standard and more flexible (because it accepts more than two arguments.

Comment: @MartinBrown another difference is `COALESCE` and `ISNULL` also have different return type rules. The return type of COALESCE will be the type of the expression with the highest precedence, whereas the return type of `ISNULL` will be the type of the first argument. `ISNULL(CONVERT(BIT, 0), 0)` returns a bit, but `COALESCE(CONVERT(BIT, 0), 0)` will return an int. There are probably not too many scenarios where this would be a deciding factor, but it could save a conversion or two at some point, or a headache wondering why your bit columns has suddenly become an int after adding coalesce.